Why can't po-groups have a greatest element?
Birkhoff defines a po-group G as a group that is also a poset and in which group translation is isotone:
\begin{gather*}
x\leq y\implies a+x+b\leq a+y+b\;\forall a,x,y,b\in G.
\end{gather*}
A trivial corollary that comes right after states such a group can't have a universal bound as the conditions above would imply $a+I=I$ for all $a$. My question is how does one get $a+I=I$? I guess $a+I\leq I$ by definition of a universal bound but how to get the reverse (without assuming a universal lower bound)?

What if you look at $I-a\leq I$ and add $a$ to both sides?

Ah ofc because of the inverse... thank you. And it would be correct to say the result doesn't hold for po-semigroups, right?

Guess not. Look at the set $X$ of positive integers together with $\infty$ and with the extended addition operation satisfying $x+\infty = \infty$ for any $x\in X$. This clearly satisfies $x\leq y$ implies $x+z\leq y+z$, but $\infty$ is an upper bound.

@AnCar Thanks again. One last question, if you can ofc (else I'll make a new post). In the same chapter he says for l-groups $a+(x\vee y)=(a+x)\vee(a+y)$;
$(a+x)\vee(a+y)\leq a+(x\vee y)$ I see but where does the reverse follow from?

I am not sure what l-groups are. I am really not a set theory guy. Maybe asking this in a new post would be better.
